# "uninitialized constant User" when setting up spree and refinery together

Tags: spree, refinerycms

I have been trying to set up spree and refinery together with the following purpose :
**using same authentification system for both**.

According a github project and a subsequent pull into spree master branch... this should go smoothly (links available in comment of first answer)

I gave a hard try but I can't get rid of "uninitialized constant User" error. I will try to describe all the necessary steps to be able to replicate the error.

Firstofall, the environnement :

```
gem install rails
rails new spreefinery
cd spreefinery

# resolve a dependency on which bundler fails
sed "s/'jquery-rails'/'jquery-rails', '~>2.0.0'/g" -i Gemfile 

echo "# adding custom gems for both spree and refinery
gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git', :branch => '1-2-stable'
gem 'spree_usa_epay'
gem 'spree_skrill'
gem 'refinerycms', :git => 'git://github.com/refinery/refinerycms.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'" >> Gemfile

bundle install
```

Secondly, install refinery as indicated in the [guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app)

```
rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation
```

with a patch for pagination

```
echo "#Refinery uses the will_paginate gem for pagination, 
# while Spree uses Kaminari.... This fix makes both happy

if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        alias_method :per, :per_page
        alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
      end
    end 
  end
end" > config/initializers/spreefinery.rb
```

Eventually, install spree (without authentification)

```
bundle exec spree install --git=git://github.com/spree/spree.git --branch=1-2-stable

# use default config except for authentification :
  Would you like to install the default gateways? (yes/no) [yes] 
  Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] no
  What is the name of the class representing users within your application? [User] 
  Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] 
  Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] 
  Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes]
```

This last command runs as :

```
 gemfile  spree
 gemfile  spree_usa_epay
 gemfile  spree_skrill
     run  bundle install from "."
  create  config/initializers/spree.rb
  create  config/spree.yml
  remove  public/index.html
  append  public/robots.txt
  create  app/assets/javascripts/store
  create  app/assets/javascripts/admin
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/store
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/admin
  create  app/assets/images/store
  create  app/assets/images/admin
  create  app/assets/javascripts/store/all.js
  create  app/assets/javascripts/admin/all.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/store/all.css
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/admin/all.css
  create  app/overrides
  append  config/environment.rb
  append  db/seeds.rb
 copying  migrations
creating  database
 running  migrations
 loading  seed data
    rake  db:seed 
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User

Tasks: TOP => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
     loading  sample data
      insert  config/routes.rb
**************************************************
We added the following line to your application's config/routes.rb file:

mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
**************************************************
Spree has been installed successfully. You're all ready to go!

Enjoy!
```

You can see the error on db:seed step.

The same error comes again on rails server or rake db:migrate. Here is the full traceback:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bundler/gems/spree-dbb0c56a60a9/core/lib/spree/core.rb:52:in `user_class'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bundler/gems/spree-dbb0c56a60a9/promo/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:7:in `<class:User>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bundler/gems/spree-dbb0c56a60a9/promo/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:4:in `<module:Rules>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bundler/gems/spree-dbb0c56a60a9/promo/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:3:in `<class:Promotion>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bundler/gems/spree-dbb0c56a60a9/promo/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:2:in `<module:Spree>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bundler/gems/spree-dbb0c56a60a9/promo/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bundler/gems/spree-dbb0c56a60a9/promo/lib/spree/promo/engine.rb:44:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/emb/Documents/envs/spreefinery/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:295:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/emb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/emb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/emb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@spreefinery/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I would need some help at this point. I have found some posts about this error stating than the model User might not exist... but refinery definitively declares a [User class](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/authentication/app/models/refinery/user.rb)... so I am a bit confused.

Thanks for your help !
Manu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it and it looks like so easy.... mmmfff

So I just had to specify the **"Refinery::User"** (not simply "User") to the question about the user.

```
Would you like to install the default gateways? (yes/no) [yes] 
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] no
What is the name of the class representing users ...? [User] **Refinery::User**
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] 
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] 
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes]
```

So logical :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install spree and run the standard migrations but I can see from your entry that you have explicitly stated NOT to install the default auth system that comes with spree (which like refinery is based on devise). Therefore some of the migrations that run on the user model are failing.

```
> bundle exec spree install --git=git://github.com/spree/spree.git
> --branch=1-2-stable
> 
    > use default config except for authentification :   Would you like to install the default gateways? (yes/no) [yes]    Would you like to
    > install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] no   What is
    > the name of the class representing users within your application?
    > [User]    Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes]   
    > Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes]    Would you like
    > to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes]
```

If you try install it again but this time say YES to "Would you like to install the default authentication system?" then it should work. I have been working on a similar system this week and its working fine. You will get two namespaced user db tables in your db, but if you want both systems sharing a single auth system then I think you are in for some work and the standard installer wont be applicable.

Comment: Yes it works fine with the both authentification systems, but it's not very convenient to have 2 independant user management on one site :) I thought that spree would use the refinery system the way I did... it appeared so reading the work on github by [pibiboily](https://github.com/jipiboily/spree_refinery_auth) which has been [integrated](https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/1512) into spree (and resulted on the option "no auth")